# Django development server command

Tags: python, django, nginx, server, web-development-server

I am a little confused about the Django development server. Here the question is if my project running based on `gunicorn` and Nginx in production environment.

Should my local development need `Nginx` for serving static files?

if yes then what command should I use instead of **Python manage.py runserver**.

Help me get out of it.

Comment: Do you set all static variable in setings.py for your local run?

Comment: yes i do set it ,but what about images that upload by users in the storage like s3 bucket...

Comment: You have to manage all variable related to media in setttings.py

Answer (score 0):

For static file, you have to manage below variables in your `settings.py`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app_name/static')
]
```

For media related thing you have to set below variables in your `settings.py`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: If i configured like you said, I can run my development server using manage.py runserver?  What you think about this  ''gunicorn -d -b 0.0.0.0:8030 -w 3 myproject.wsgi''

Comment: Yes, you can run it locally using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: For collect all static files first you have to run "python manage.py collectstatic" command.